# React Native and Hardhat

Tags: dapps, hardhat, nodejs

I can't seem to find much documentation on this topic, but I am building a Dapp in React Native with Expo. However, I know that Expo is hard to work with when it comes to libraries with dependencies on Node.js. Is it possible to use Hardhat with Expo, or should I switch to using React Native CLI?